# react-native textInput value return [object Object]

Tags: javascript, react-native, setstate

I've got a component with 4 TextInput representing business hours
I want to concatenate the first 2 (representing opening time) and store them in my state. But I have a return value of type : **[object Object]:[object Object]**

this is the first two input:

```
                 <CustomInput
                  underlineColorAndroid="#58CAF1"
                  style={styles.inputScheduleTime}
                  // ref="lundiStart"
                  placeholder="8H00..."
                  keyboardType="numeric"
                  onBlur={ input => {
                      let input1 = input;
                      this.setState({ monday: {
                        start: input1 ,
                        end: ""
                        }
                      });
                  }
                }
                />
                <CustomInput
                  underlineColorAndroid="#58CAF1"
                  style={styles.inputScheduleTime}
                  // ref="lundiStart"
                  placeholder="8H00..."
                  keyboardType="numeric"
                  onBlur={ input => {
                    let input2 = input;
                      this.setState({ monday: {
                        start:this.state.monday.start + ':' + input2,
                        end: ""
                        }
                      });
                  }
                }
                />
```

And my state is like that:

```
  monday: {
        start: "",
        end: ""
      },
```

has your opinion on why?
how to store them properly?

===================  **SOLUTION** ==================

With **onBlur** like in my situation and with react-native , you can access to the value with : **input.nativeEvent.text**

With this I was able to set my state cleanly !!

Answer (score 2):

Set the value of `input1` and `input2` to `input.target.value`.

You're getting `event` back (which is an object, not a string) and trying to concatenate that together, thereby resulting in `[object Object]:[object Object]`.

Getting the event's target value (which is the input field), should give you what you require.

Comment: when i try that, **let input1 = input.target.value** the value is **undefined**

Answer (score 1):

**Take a look at this [example](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html).**

The most common way to reflect input-values in React is to update the state on every single change, so it has a reliable value in it.

**If you really want to use onBlur:**

Are you sure, your onBlur-Callback returns a string? Check the Value, returned in input and make sure the type is right.

Comment: when i use "onChangeText" i've got this prob: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49239811/react-native-textinput-and-firebase-concatenation-issues-when-i-store-my-value?noredirect=1#comment85496365_49239811   that's why i want use "onBlur"

Answer (score 0):

This is old thread but encountered similar issue and solved it using the following

Update

```
onBlur={text => SetContent(text)}
```

To

```
onBlur={({ text }) => SetContent(text)}
```

Note: Wrapped text in Parenthesis and curly brackets